# ElasticSearch Nest: AutoMap with DynamicTemplates

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying use a dynamic template in ES such that all string fields are multifields.  I also want to apply some specific mappings to certain fields.

Take the following example class:

```cs
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "sample1")]
public class Sample1
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
    public string DoNotIndex { get; set; }

    public string MultiField1 { get; set; }

    public string MultiField2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to then create the dynamic template and apply the mapping to `DoNotIndex` using the following command:

```cs
_client.Map<Sample1>(m => m
  .AutoMap()
  .DynamicTemplates(dt=> dt
      .DynamicTemplate("all_strings_multifields", t => t
        .MatchMappingType("string")
        .Mapping(tm => tm
            .String(mf => mf
                .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
                .Fields(mff => mff
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name("raw")
                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    )
)
.VerifySuccessfulResponse();
```

The result is:

```json
{
  "test1": {
    "mappings": {
      "sample1": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "all_strings_multifields": {
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
                },
                "index": "analyzed",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "doNotIndex": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": false
          },
          "iD": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "multiField1": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "multiField2": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Results

you'll see that the `DoNotIndex` property is indeed correct, but the `multifield1` and `multifield2` are not correct (they are not multi fields).

## Workaround

I know I can "fix" this by *NOT* doing the `AutoMap()` and instead specifying each of the special indexes but there are a lot of fields and that isn't as clean of a solution.

Can I do AutoMap with DynamicTemplates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/dynamic-templates.html) only apply to fields that are dynamically added to a mapping, so properties explicitly mapped with `.AutoMap()` will not be affected by dynamic mapping.

There is however a way to apply conventions to explicit mappings with NEST using the visitor pattern. It looks like you're using Elasticsearch 5.0, [so you should use the `text` and `keyword` mappings.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

First define a visitor

```cs
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "sample1")]
public class Sample1
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Keyword(Index = false)]
    public string DoNotIndex { get; set; }

    public string MultiField1 { get; set; }

    public string MultiField2 { get; set; }
}

public class AllStringsMultiFieldsVisitor : NoopPropertyVisitor
{
    public override void Visit(ITextProperty type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase attribute)
    {
        // if a custom attribute has been applied, let it take precedence
        if (propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase>() == null)
        {
            type.Fields = new Properties
            {
                {
                    "raw", new KeywordProperty()
                }
            };
        }

        base.Visit(type, propertyInfo, attribute);
    }
}
```

Then pass an instance of the visitor to `.AutoMap()`

```cs
client.Map<Sample1>(m => m
    .AutoMap(new AllStringsMultiFieldsVisitor())
    .DynamicTemplates(dt => dt
        .DynamicTemplate("all_strings_multifields", t => t
            .MatchMappingType("text")
            .Mapping(tm => tm
                .Text(mf => mf
                    .Index(true)
                    .Fields(mff => mff
                        .Keyword(s => s
                            .Name("raw")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

produces

```json
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "all_strings_multifields": {
        "match_mapping_type": "text",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "index": true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "iD": {
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "doNotIndex": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": false
    },
    "multiField1": {
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "multiField2": {
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

I should point out however that the [default automapping for a C# `string` property in NEST 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/auto-map.html#_simple_automapping) is to map it as a `text` field with a `keyword` sub field with `ignore_above:256`. [NEST 5.0 was released to nuget earlier this week](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/5.0.0)

```cs
client.Map<Sample1>(m => m
    .AutoMap()
    .DynamicTemplates(dt => dt
        .DynamicTemplate("all_strings_multifields", t => t
            .MatchMappingType("text")
            .Mapping(tm => tm
                .Text(mf => mf
                    .Index(true)
                    .Fields(mff => mff
                        .Keyword(s => s
                            .Name("raw")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

produces

```json
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "all_strings_multifields": {
        "match_mapping_type": "text",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "index": true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "iD": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "doNotIndex": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": false
    },
    "multiField1": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "multiField2": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: YES!  Thank you Russ, the sample code with the visitor pattern worked great.  I tweaked it for ES 2.x instead of 5.x and everything looks good.  You rock!